# how to add a line break on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

really simple question and cant figure it out. I am trying to add a line break here on my table header

```
var text = "<table id='test' class='test'>";
    text += "<tr><th> style='font-size:16px'>Cool \nStuff</th></tr>";
```

I have tried to add a line break using `<br>` and `\n` and no luck, can anyone help me

Comment: `\n` should work fine

Comment: `<br>` should work. `\n` will not make a difference

Comment: yeah its suppose to work but is not.. im using datatables plugin and im building my table dynamically

Comment: @user3547086 It would help if you put the exact code into your question that does not work!

Comment: you have a typo at `<th>` .. the style tag is outside the tag.. And please see my answer. The `<br>` tag works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` puts a newline in the string, but HTML treats newlines as spaces. To put in a line break, you:

1. Use a `<br>` ("break") element:

   ```
   var text = "<table id='test' class='test'>";
       text += "<tr><th style='font-size:16px'>Cool<br>Stuff</th></tr>";
   ```

   or,
2. Put the first line in one block element, the second in another:

   ```
   var text = "<table id='test' class='test'>";
       text += "<tr><th style='font-size:16px'>" +
               "<div>Cool</div>" +
               "<div>Stuff</div>" +
               "</th></tr>";
   ```

That sort of thing.

Comment: The first suggestion didn't work but the second one did. Thank you, I will accept your answer whenever it lets me

Answer (score 2):

Use `<br>` should work fine. Note you had a typo with the opening `th`

```js
var text = "<table id='test' class='test'>";
    text +=  "<thead>";
    text += "<tr><th style='font-size:16px'>Cool <br/>Stuff</th></tr>";
    text +=  "</thead>";
    text +=  "</table>";


document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="z"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `</br>` should work, see the code snippet below. Please note that there is an error in your HTML. `<th> style='font-size:16px'>` contains two closing `>` tags, you should remove the first one.

```js
var text = "<table id='test' class='test'>";
text += "<tr><th style='font-size:16px'> Cool </br> Stuff</th></tr>";
document.write(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate each line in the header into `<span>Cool</span><span>Stuff</span>` and add the following styles to the span:

```
span {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
// using your javascript example...

var text = "<table id='test' class='test'>";
    text += "<tr><th> style='font-size:16px'><span style='width:100%; display:block;'>Cool</span><span style='width:100%; display:block;>Stuff</span></th></tr>";
```

```css
.table {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 2px #d2d2d2;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.table > thead > tr > th > span {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table"><!-- START TABLE -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Cool</span><span>Stuff</span></th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
    </tbody>
</table><!-- /END TABLE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<br>` works perfectly.

```
(function () {
    text += '<th>Cool<br>Stuff</th>';
})();
```

[Relevant JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9Lu7211/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/68Lc0d7t/1/

You missed the closing tag in the `<th>` tag.. Above is a simple working fiddle with `<br>` tag.